# mysql like textfield and varchar only varchar returned

Tags: mysql, text, field, sql-like, varchar

I have two tables.  One contains two text fields along with other fields.  The other table contains a varchar field.  I want to search these three fields using LIKE %keyword%.  When I search only the text fields or the varchar fields it works.  When I try searching all three only the varchar is being searched.  Here is the sql

```
SELECT * 
        FROM modx_expertise e
        INNER JOIN modx_expertise_appraiser ea ON e.expertise_id = ea.expertise_id
        INNER JOIN modx_web_user_attributes ua ON ua.internalKey = ea.internalKey
        INNER JOIN modx_web_user_attributes_extended uae ON uae.internalKey = ua.internalkey
        WHERE uae.specialities
         OR uae.bio
         OR e.expertise
         LIKE  '%$keyword%'
         GROUP BY fname, lname";
```

Comment: Basically add the `like` keyword for each of the columns, posted my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
        FROM modx_expertise e
        INNER JOIN modx_expertise_appraiser ea ON e.expertise_id = ea.expertise_id
        INNER JOIN modx_web_user_attributes ua ON ua.internalKey = ea.internalKey
        INNER JOIN modx_web_user_attributes_extended uae ON uae.internalKey = ua.internalkey
        WHERE uae.specialities
         LIKE  '%$keyword%'
         OR uae.bio
         LIKE  '%$keyword%'
         OR e.expertise
         LIKE  '%$keyword%'
         GROUP BY fname, lname";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
WHERE uae.specialities LIKE  '%$keyword%'
OR uae.bio LIKE  '%$keyword%'
OR e.expertise LIKE  '%$keyword%'
...
```